# Jquery Multi select check boxed tree view within a dropdown (Dropdown Tree)

Tags: jquery

As the question title describes , I want a dropdown which contains a tree inside it , the tree should be a checkboxed tree and i can multi select tree nodes from there. There's a Telerik control which provides exactly the same functionality.

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdowntree/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx

I want this kind of control in jquery. Is there a one for me ?

There's this thread

[JSF Tree in a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214365/jsf-tree-in-a-dropdown)

which points to the same kind of issue and there's a solution for it with "optgroup" but that is not a multiselect dropdown. I want that same thing but which is multi selectable and selecting the root node selects all the child nodes automatically.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please try to do what you want and if you have issues, come back with specific questions and we can help.

Comment: Mr  Darren Sweeney i am asking for a jquery plugin if there's  one available , what kind of code you expect from me ? ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214365/jsf-tree-in-a-dropdown check this question , it got 11 upvotes , have you got any sense ? ..

Comment: This question is very off topic at SO. Please visit the [help] - point 4 to see why

Comment: @umer : I've added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example of https://josephskh.github.io/repos/dropdowntree/ here.

```js
$(function() {
var arr4=[
{title:"A",href:"#1",dataAttrs:[{title:"dataattr1",data:"value1"},{title:"dataattr2",data:"value2"},{title:"dataattr3",data:"value3"}]}
,
{title:"B",href:"#2",dataAttrs:[{title:"dataattr4",data:"value4"},{title:"dataattr5",data:"value5"},{title:"dataattr6",data:"value6"}]}
,
{title:"C",href:"#3",dataAttrs:[{title:"dataattr7",data:"value7"},{title:"dataattr8",data:"value8"},{title:"dataattr9",data:"value9"}]}
];
var arr3=[
{title:"P",href:"#1",dataAttrs:[{title:"dataattr1",data:"value1"},{title:"dataattr2",data:"value2"},{title:"dataattr3",data:"value3"}]}
,
{title:"Q",href:"#2",dataAttrs:[{title:"dataattr4",data:"value4"},{title:"dataattr5",data:"value5"},{title:"dataattr6",data:"value6"}],data:arr4}
,
{title:"R",href:"#3",dataAttrs:[{title:"dataattr7",data:"value7"},{title:"dataattr8",data:"value8"},{title:"dataattr9",data:"value9"}]}
];

  var options2 = {
    title: "Select",
    data: arr3,
    maxHeight: 3000,
    clickHandler: function(element) {
      //gets clicked element parents
      $("#firstDropDownTree2").SetTitle($(element).find("a").first().text());

    },
    closedArrow: '<i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    openedArrow: '<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    multiSelect: true,
    selectChildren: true

  }

  $("#firstDropDownTree").DropDownTree(options2);
});
```

```css
.dropdown-tree>ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-tree li {
  list-style: none
}

.dropdown-tree li>i {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dropdown-tree li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.dropdown-tree li:hover ul {
  background: white;
}

.dropdown-tree li:hover ul li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.dropdown-tree a {
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent !important;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-tree .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/*RTL CSS*/

.rtl-dropdown-tree {
  direction: rtl !important
}

.rtl-dropdown-tree>ul {
  right: 0;
  left: unset;
  text-align: right
}

.rtl-dropdown-tree .arrow {
  right: 6px
}

.rtl-dropdown-tree li>i {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://josephskh.github.io/repos/dropdowntree/dropdowntree.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown dropdown-tree" id="firstDropDownTree">
```